# How to use LISTAGG in AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to use LISTAGG for querying in Amazon Athena.
Are there any ways to aggregate data into list or string?

As [Amazon Athena User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-ug.pdf),

> The grouping_expressions element can be any function (such as SUM, AVG, COUNT, etc.)

Answer (score 19):

#### Option 1: array

```
with t(i) as (select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) 
select  array_agg(i) as result 
from    t
;

  result
-----------
 [3, 2, 1]
```

---

#### Option 2: string

```
with t(i) as (select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) 
select  array_join(array_agg(i),',') as result 
from    t
;

 result
--------
 1,3,2
```

Answer (score -1):

try this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html)

Syntax

```
LISTAGG( [DISTINCT] aggregate_expression [, 'delimiter' ] ) 
[ WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_list) ]
```

Examples

```
SELECT LISTAGG(sellerid, ', ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sellerid) 
FROM sales WHERE eventid = 4337;
```