# group by more than one column

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to select three columns from a table and group by the results according to two of the. i.e, if i have columns x, y, z, I want results like (x1, y1): [z1, z9, z11 ....], (x2, y2): [z3, z12, z33 ...], ...

I tried the next (ATHENA) query:

```
SELECT region, family, tenancy, platform, size_factor, duration
FROM default.sell_durations
WHERE CAST(creation_date as timestamp) BETWEEN CAST(? as timestamp) AND CAST(? as timestamp)
group by region, family, tenancy, platform, size_factor
```

and i got the next error:

> Failed to Execute Athena query, status: FAILED, reason: SYNTAX_ERROR:
> line 1:56: 'duration' must be an aggregate expression or appear in
> GROUP BY clause

Comment: Hi - what about the error message do you not understand?

Comment: Don't you instead want `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use LISTAGG in AWS Athena?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821474/how-to-use-listagg-in-aws-athena)

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the aggregation functions. In this case based on description [`array_agg`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#array_agg) seems to be an appropriate one:

```sql
SELECT region, family, tenancy, platform, size_factor, array_agg(duration)
FROM default.sell_durations
WHERE CAST(creation_date as timestamp) BETWEEN CAST(? as timestamp) AND CAST(? as timestamp)
group by region, family, tenancy, platform, size_factor
```